# Why can't I ssh or ping my brand new Amazon EC2 instance?

Tags: ssh, firewall, amazon-ec2, ping

I just created a free EC2 instance with all the defaults. It says it's running in the AWS Management Console.  On the "Instance Actions" menu, I click "Connect".  I copy the DNS name provided (looks like ec2-a-dashed-IP-address.compute-1.amazonaws.com) and try to SSH to it.  No response.  I can't even ping it. What gives?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/227804/why-cant-i-ssh-into-my-new-ec2-instance/353818#353818

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Apparently the default firewall is locked down, even though it doesn't look like it. Go to "Security Groups" on the left-hand pane of the AWS console, and select the "default" group. There are already entries for all TCP,UDP, and ICMP from a Source of "default group".

For a new entry at the bottom, select "SSH" from the "Connection Method" dropdown.  The Source will default to "0.0.0.0/0" instead of "default group".  Click "Save" over on the right and now it should respond when you try to SSH in.

If you want to ping it, create a similar new entry with protocol "ICMP", leaving the Connection Method as "Custom..."

Comment: Posting this in case it's helpful, but maybe it's painfully obvious to everyone but me.  I expect things to be locked down by default, but not so much that I can't even ping my own instance!  Maybe the "Connect Help" dialog that pops up in response to "Instance Actions"->"Connect" should at least make a mention of it if you have yourself locked out...

Answer (score 1):

The way I got ping to work was:

- Select Inbound -> Custom ICMP
- Select "Echo Request"
- Set Source if needed or use 0.0.0.0/0 for everywhere
- Apply

(ssh worked out of the box for my instance)